# Mango tree looking poorly!

Tags: fruit-trees

We have a 4year old mango tree that now has browning leaves on the edges.

We live in Perth Australia near the ocean and it's exposed to full sunlight and heat. But it's only spring and the big heat is yet to start.

Any advice on what I need to do?
[image: sad mango]

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it is planted quite close between a wall and kerb. The footing for that wall is probably taking up most of its root space. I'd say it is lacking nutrients and room to grow beneath the surface. A smaller species would be more suitable in this narrow location.

Comment: Thanks for that.  So what do you think is best next, transplant or more nutrients?

Comment: I would remove the mango, hopefully there is somewhere else that you can put it? Then  if you can I'd add another, more suitably sized species here. Perhaps a hedge is more suitable than a tree. Is the concrete kerb in the photo an edge to a private road or driveway? You may be restricted by local legislation on what you can or can't do to the existing tree or what you can plant here. Perhaps check first!

Answer (score 1):

Water! It needs much more water than your are giving it.

Comment: Yes, it need water, but the root cause is that it is absolutely not planter in the right place.